# Stream std::sync::mpsc::Receiver results from function

Tags: rust, stream, mpsc

How do I stream the contents of an [std::sync::mpsc::Receiver](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html) from a function?

The caller should be able to receive results before all the results are available.

Ideally, I'd like the return type of `fetch_all()` to be independent of `std::sync::mpsc` so something like `impl Iterator<Item = &'a Result<FooResult<'a>, FooError<'a>>>` is preferred.

The code below doesn't work because `rx` is allocated on the stack so it cannot be returned.

I suppose the caller could pass `tx` and `rx` into `fetch_all()`, is there a way to avoid this?

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};

fn fetch(item: &'a str) -> Result<FooResult<'a>, FooError<'a>> {}

fn fetch_all(items: &'a [&'a str]) -> ??? { // What's the best return type?
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    let pool = ThreadPool::new(10);

    for i in items {
        let txx = tx.clone();
        let item = i.to_owned();
        pool.execute(move || {
            let r = fetch(item)
            txx.send(r).expect("Thread communication error");
        });
    }

    pool.join();
    std::mem::drop(sender); 

    rx.into_iter() // <- what should this be?
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can make this work; what you are sending to the channel will have a shorter lifetime than the outer `'a` because its derived from `item` which gets destroyed at the end of the `pool.execute` closure. You can maybe avoid that by using [threadpool-scope](https://crates.io/crates/threadpool_scope) so you can pass local references.

Comment: @kmdreko there must be a way to put the items on the heap with reference counting

Comment: @kmdreko `threadpool-scope` doesn't help, unfortunately, because if scope is fully resolved inside `fetch_all()`, then the OP loses the ability to return `rx.into_iter()`. E.g. the [code](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/9af3605babdd1ead78d8580f5510a236) from my deleted answer compiles but deadlocks because `threadpool_scope::scope_with()` waits for all threads to finish, which is the opposite of what returning `rx.into_iter()` is intended to achieve. I think what the OP wants to achieve is impossible in safe Rust.

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done, because it would be unsound.

For the code to be sound, `items` must be alive while the threads are running. But assuming we return immediately without letting the threads finish, the caller might destroy `items` and we'll have a use-after-free.

Of course, as @user4815162342 suggested, we can let the threads finish, but then this isn't "streaming" anymore. We essentially just fill a `Vec` with the results.

We can do a little better, though: we can shift the pool creation to the caller. Then, we can still only run while the pool is alive, but the caller decides when to kill it - and so, we expand the scope of running for all the caller wants. So the caller may include the processing of the streamed values in this scope, and then we will have true streaming.

Example:

```rust
use scoped_threadpool::{Pool, Scope};
use std::sync::mpsc;

fn fetch_all<'a: 'scope, 'pool, 'scope>(
    items: &'a [&'a str],
    scope: &Scope<'pool, 'scope>,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<FooResult<'a>, FooError<'a>>> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    for i in items {
        let tx = tx.clone();
        scope.execute(move || {
            let r = fetch(i);
            tx.send(r).expect("Thread communication error");
        });
    }

    rx.into_iter()
}

fn main() {
    let mut pool = Pool::new(10);
    pool.scoped(|scope| {
        let iter = fetch_all(&["a", "b", "c"], scope);
        for item in iter {
            // Process `item`...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: passing `mpsc::channel())` to `fetch_all()` instead of `scoped_threadpool::Scope` is probably a better solution

Comment: @Jay But it won't help you to stream them.

Answer (score 0):

The **first problem** with the original code is that the results of `fetch()` cannot reference arguments to `fetch_all()` (without `std::sync::Arc`) since `fetch()` will be run on a thread that continues to exist after `fetch_all()` has returned. In other words, we need to allow the input argument `items` to be destroyed before the results by removing the lifetime parameters and making any necessary str copies (unless we want to pass `item` as `Arc<&str>` to avoid copying).

The purpose of the lifetime parameters in the original code was to allow `FooResult` and `FooError` to have a reference to `item` without copying it, but the correct way to do this is with `std::sync::Arc`, not lifetime parameters.

The function signatures should be:

```
fn fetch(item: &str) -> Result<FooResult, FooError> {}
fn fetch_all(items: &[&'str]) ->  impl Iterator<Item = Result<FooResult, FooError>> {}
```

---

The **second problem** with the original code is that `let item = i.to_owned();` doesn't copy the item; neither does `let item = i.clone();` The item needs to be copied since it needs to exist inside the thread after `fetch_all()` returns.

The correct code is `let item = String::from(i);`

---

The complete solution:

```
pub fn fetch(item: &str) -> Result<FooResult, FooError> {}

pub fn fetch_all(
  items: &[&str],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<FooResult, FooError>> {
  let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
  let pool = ThreadPool::new(10);

  for &i in items {
    let item = String::from(i);
    let txx = tx.clone();
    pool.execute(move || {
      let r = fetch(&item);
      txx.send(r).expect("Thread communication error");
    });
  }

  rx.into_iter()
}
```

This works, but an ideal solution would allow a single implementation of `fetch()` that supports `&String`, `&str`, `Arc<&str>`, `Arc<&String>` as item type and copies in the case of `&String` or `&str` but not in the case of `Arc`, but I haven't figured this out yet.

Comment: If you can make `FooResult` and `FooError` not depend on `item`, sure, that's the best solution.

Comment: I don't understand the third problem. Why is the delay in dropping of `tx` required? Is there an issue if you do nothing (i.e. drop `tx` at the end of `fetch_all()`)?